# mozilla_django_oidc package returning redirect error

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, keycloak

Getting the following error while trying to login with keycloak through django application (mozilla_django_oidc). Settings, redirect URI - everything looks fine. After providing the login credentials, it suppose to redirect to the app itself and by that time encountering this error. Any idea?

[image]